# Magento block file is not showing up some times

Tags: magento, templates

Catalog.xml

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="top.menu">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml">
          <block type="catalog/navigation" name="topnav_extra" template="catalog/navigation/top_extra.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

top_extra.phtml

```
<ul>
<li> Custom Menu1 </li>
<li> Custom Menu2 </li>
</ul>
```

top.phtml

```
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<ul id="topnav">
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
    <!-- Header Menu laset tab start here --> 
<?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('topnav_extra');  ?>
</ul>
```

This block is not showing sometimes when i refreshing twice or thrice it's coming. I am doing reindexing and cache refreshing on daily using cron. But i dont know why its coming randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/top_extra.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

i include that file with out layout handles. I am not sure is the right way to do this? but its showing up. I put log to know how many times its not showing up.. Will see

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a caching issue to me. Try calling your custom menu via PHP instead of XML

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_id')- >toHtml(); ?>
```

This will alleviate any issues you might encounter using the XML files. Hope this helps!

Comment: But i need to make some css conditions through php which can be done from phtml file not in cms block. So please let me know if there any other idea to show my custom menu along with my original menu. My code failed to display 1 in 5 times.

Comment: @SatheeshNarayanan do you have a visual we can see?